# Problema al utilizar Ajax en Laravel usando JSON

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, json, model-view-controller

me gustaria que a través de un input al poner una letra (o varias) busque en la base de datos la ciudad que estás buscando y lo devuelva en una tabla. Realmente no sé qué me puede estar fallando. La base de datos consta de varias tablas pero solo quiero que me saque los datos de una, que se llama "casas", en ella hay campos como id, ciudad, precio, etc. Solo quiero que me saque datos de esos 3 campos. Mi código lo pongo a continuación:

Aquí está el JS:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });

$('#search').on('keyup',function() { 
    
        $valor = $(this).val();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/search',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'busca': $valor},
            
            success:function(datos) {
                
                salida = $("tbody").empty();
                
                if ( datos.id === 'n')
                    $('tbody').append('No hay datos');
                else
                {
                    for (var i=0; i<datos.length; i++) {
                        salida += '<tr>';
                        salida += '<td>'+datos[i].id+'</td>';
                        salida += '<td>'+datos[i].ciudad+'</td>';
                        salida += '<td>'+datos[i].precio+'</td>';
                        salida+= '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('tbody').append(salida);
                }  
            }
        });
        
});
```

Este es el controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\casas; //aqui es la tabla de la bbdd que va a utilizar


class BuscaController extends Controller
{
   public function indexCiudad(Request $request) //tenia indexDescripcion
   {
       if ( $request->ajax())
       {
           $casas = casas::where('ciudad','like',$request->busca.'%')->get(); //casas es el nombre de la tabla, dentro de la tabla buscará el campo ciudad.
           if ($casas->count() > 0)
               return response()->json($casas);
           else
               return response()->json(['id'=>'n']);
       }
   }
   
}
```

Esta es la ruta:

```
Route::view('/busca', 'casas.busca');
      Route::get('/search', 'BuscaController@indexCiudad');
```

Este es el script colocado al final de la plantilla base:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/ajax.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la vista final donde debería salir el input con la búsqueda y devolver la tabla:

```
@extends ('layouts.app') //esta es la llamada a la plantilla base
@section ('content')

   <div class="container">
    <div align="center">
   
    </div>
    <div class ="row">
        <h2 align="center">BUSQUEDA</h2>
        <br>
    <div class="form-group">
            Descripción: <input type="text" class="form-controller"
                                id="search" name="search"></input>
    </div>
        
       <table border="1" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" align="center" width="75%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nº Referencia de la casa</th>
                    <th>Ciudad</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>   //aqui deberia salir la respuesta de la petición Ajax
        </table>   
   </div> 
   </div>
<br>
<br>
    <div id="foot">
       
<a href="/">Vuelta a principal</a>

    </div>


@endsection
```

Gracias si sois capaces de ayudarme y disculpar las molestias.

El error es que voy a la view que tendría que realizar la función que estoy buscando web1.test/search y no recibe datos, básicamente sale en blanco.

Un saludo!

Comment: Deberías agregar que prueba has hecho, que error recibes

Comment: El error es que voy a la view que tendría que realizar la función que estoy buscando web.test/search y no recibe datos, sale en blanco.

Comment: En consola tal vez te da algún error, o podés ver los logs en la carpeta storage/logs y ver si te dice algo sobre el error

Comment: En /search no me dice nada. Si ejecuto el script en otra vista me pone lo siguiente: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://web.test/js/popper.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: Fijate si no te falta popper, algo así <script src="./js/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> o buscá una ruta cdn

Comment: No entiendo, entonces el problema esta en la vista al intentar acceder a ella?

Comment: Me pone en la primera línea del Script este error en la consola Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at ajax.js:1. El código de ese Script es el primero que cuelgo.  $.ajaxSetup({ headers:....ETC.